# Center vertically and horizontally simultaneously

Tags: android, xml

I've tried everything, so I decided to post my question here maybe you can help me.

I am creating a basic application just to learn the simplest features. I created a background and 3 buttons for my application, I put these 3 buttons in a LinearLayout for each, in order to center them horizontally on the screen, and I thought that I could create a LinearLayout out these 3 to center them vertically but does not work for me.

Then I created another LinearLayout that pushes them down, but it prevents the usability with different devices, because each screen size I would have to modify this push.

Here's a picture:

[image: button arrangment]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:background="@drawable/raintumblrr">

<LinearLayout 
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingTop="32dip" 
    android:paddingBottom="15dip">     
 </LinearLayout>

 <LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center">

 <LinearLayout 
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingTop="5dip" 
    android:paddingBottom="5dip"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal">
```

and then the buttons.

can someone help me?

Comment: Thank you and sorry at the same time, i've searched for it but couldn't find nothing, i'll try to use the 'Layout alignment Query' and see how it works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a RelativeLayout, put your LinearLayout in it, with `centerInParent="true"` attribute, and `wrap_content dimensions`.